# "magento/module-new-relic-reporting" not installed after upgrade

Tags: magento2, upgrade, setup-di-compile, compiler

So, I did a lot of research and tried a lot of ideas to solve this but without luck. That's why I'm asking.

I'm trying to upgrade magento from 2.3.3 to 2.4.4 . I stacked on a problem that "magento/module-new-relic-reporting" is not installed by composer and causing problem during setup:di:complie :

```
Impossible to process constructor argument Parameter #0 [ <required> Magento\NewRelicReporting\Model\Config $config ] of Magento\GraphQl\Model\Query\Logger\NewRelic class  

Class "Magento\NewRelicReporting\Model\Config" does not exist
```

Please give me some clues ...

Comment: Seems like this package is left out by some issues, simply you can again install this package by this command - "composer require magento/module-new-relic-reporting".Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First check this class is exist or not
"Magento\NewRelicReporting\Model\Config".

If not exist then remove the module & install again using the below commands-

```
composer remove magento/module-new-relic-reporting
composer clear-cache
composer require magento/module-new-relic-reporting
```